# How to define multiple analyzers for an elasticsearch index via NEST client fluent syntax

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm having trouble defining multiple analyzers (and tokenfilters for that matter) using NEST v7.6.0

For example, with this config

```
_client.Indices.Create(Settings.GetElasticIndex(), c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Analyzers(aa => aa.Standard("standard_english", sa => sa.StopWords("_english_")))
            .Analyzers(aa => aa.Custom("randomcustom", sa => sa.Tokenizer("standard"))))
        )
        .Map<POCO>(mm => 
            mm.AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.Field1).Analyzer("standard_english"))
                    .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.Field2).Analyzer("randomcustom"))
            )
        )
    );
```

I receive the following error on index creation:

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.. Call: Status code 400 from: PUT /xxx. ServerError: Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: analyzer [standard_english] not found for field [xxx]" CausedBy: "Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "analyzer [standard_english] not found for field [xxx]"

If I switch the definitions I can reference the standard_english analyzer but not the randomcustom analyzer, so last in wins. How do I use the fluent syntax to define multiple analyzers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
_client.Indices.Create(Settings.GetElasticIndex(), c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Analyzers(aa => aa
                .Standard("standard_english", sa => sa.StopWords("_english_"))
                .Custom("randomcustom", sa => sa.Tokenizer("standard"))
            )
        )
        .Map<POCO>(mm => 
            mm.AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.Field1).Analyzer("standard_english"))
                    .Text(t => t.Name(n => n.Field2).Analyzer("randomcustom"))
            )
        )
    );
```